# How to push a node appplication that contains a react folder as a client folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, express

I have a node application that consists of a create-react-app folder as a subfolder-->client. When I try to push it to github only the node application gets pushed whereas the client folder remain empty. I even deleted the .git folder in my react folder but still doesnt work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does it say in your `.gitignore` file?

Comment: Please add your directory structure as well as .gitignore file